# problem with video HDMI video output, distorted image

Tags: hdmi, android, config.txt

I am playing with a Rpi3 distro (Android Raspand) and I can't see anything. Image is twisted and distorted, please see how 
[image]
[image]

I am playing with config.txt following this guide https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tags/config.txt/info

Please see original config.txt file:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=4
disable_overscan=1
framebuffer_width=1280
framebuffer_height=720
kernel=zImage
device_tree=bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
dtparam=audio=on
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,cma-256
initramfs ramdisk.img 0x01f00000
mask_gpu_interrupt0=0x400
avoid_warnings=2
gpu_mem=256
enable_uart=1
```

I tried to replicate content from working config.txt distros I already tested, but none works :-(

I tried older Raspand images and they worked well also.

Can you please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and insert the pictures rather than linking to a 3rd party service

Comment: You can also look at the [official documentation for video options](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md). What resolutions can your monitor handle? What is its standard ratio?

Comment: thanks, I have checked it already, this rpi3 works very well with a lot of distros I have tried. It is standard monitor. I tried a 2nd monitor too... I don't know but Image an colors are showed, but distorted... I tried hdmi_safe=1 :-(

Comment: it is solved, just changing to another monitor... it works